# Background-attachment: fixed and skew in chrome webkit

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm having an issue in Chrome. I have two `<section>` elements with `background-attachment: fixed`. When I apply a CSS3 `skewY` transform, the second `<section>` renders incorrectly.

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/C3est/17/embedded/result/) of the problem. If you open it in chrome, scroll down. The second `<section>` doesn't scroll up correctly. If you open it in Safari, you can see the expected behavior.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What is exactly the problem sam ?

Comment: @EricoAugustin When you scroll down in chrome, the second element doesn't move up

Comment: On mozilla ff the white cat didnt get the skewY value too ?

Comment: @EricoAugustin works now, forgot the vendor prefix. So the problem is still just chrome.

Comment: @EricoAugustin do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes, i see. It can be aplied using -webkit-keyframes but when it applied the skew effect was gone.